# httpd (apache) Wildcard in Location?

Tags: apache, proxy, flask-restx

I'm trying to proxy my apache requests to a flaskrestx api.

```
<Location ~ "/hosts/*/patchstatus">
  ProxyPass http://my.company.com:8082/rest_api/hosts/(.*)/patchstatus
  ProxyPassReverse http://my.company.com:8082/rest_api/hosts/(.*)/patchstatus
</Location>
```

This always returns a 504 proxy error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request<p>Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>
```

The (.*) is a hostname that can change depending on what is passed. How do I properly route this request past the proxy?

Comment: Note that `~` requires a regular expression, and `/hosts/*/patchstatus` is invalid (unless you really mean to match `hostspatchstatus`, `hosts/patchstatus`, `hosts//patchstatus`, etc). I think you want `<Location ~ "/hosts/.*/patchstatus">`.

Comment: I changed that and now I get the following:
```Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.```